# Column Store Strategies

Tags: oracle, mongodb, blob

We have an app that requires very fast access to columns from delimited flat files, whithout knowing in advance what columns will be in the files. My initial approach was to store each column in a MongoDB document as a array, but it does not scale as the files get bigger as I hit the 16MB document limit.

My second approach is to split the file columnwise and essentially treat them as blobs that can be served off disk to the client app. I'd intuitively think that storing the location in database and the files on disk is the best approach, and that storing them in a database as blobs (or in mongo gridfs) is adding unnessasary overhead, however there may be advatages that are not apparant to me at the moment. So my question is: what would be the advantage to storing them as blobs in a database such as (Oracle/Mongo) and are there any databases that are particularly well suited to this task.

Thanks,
Vackar

Comment: I'd rather not copy the docs for GridFS as they describe the "when" quite well: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-when-to-use-gridfs

Comment: You should provide sample lines from that 'delimited flat files'